# Deploying Win10 with Windows Deployment Services

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wds, windows-10

I'm trying to deploy Windows 10 Pro with WDS on Server 2008 R2. I successfully uploaded a boot image (boot.wim) to WDS, but when I try to add the install image (install.wim) I get the following error: "The file does not contain a valid install image." Both .wim files have been extracted from an ISO file. Has the latter file corrupted, or is it possible that the 2008 R2 version of WDS doesn't support deploying Windows 10? Is there any workaround available? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Apparently `install.wim` used an incompatible compression, so what I needed to do was:

```
dism.exe /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:C:\install.wim /SourceIndex:1 /DestinationImageFile:C:\install2.wim /Compress:max
```

For this you need **Deployment Tools ja Windows Preinstallation Environment** which can be downloaded [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=526740). Then `dism.exe` can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools`.